# How can I fetch nodelist with document.querySelectorAll in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

This is a part of an e-commerce app in which customers can select an order and go to checkout. A group of similar buttons that have a data- attribute, with respective extensions to data-**something**. I am able to implement this well in JavaScript and Html 5. I want to know how to achieve exactly the same using Angular.

```
    
          <button data-plan="bronze">Select Plan</button>
          <button data-plan="silver">Select Plan</button>
          <button data-plan="gold">Select Plan</button>
          <button data-plan="diamond">Select Plan</button>
```

Below is JavaScript I wish to implement in Angular,

```
// Select Plan Logic
    const planButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-plan]");
```

Comment: You should simplify the code to the bare minimum so people understand your issue. Also, try to be a little more specific

Comment: Okay, let me break it into bits and pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interact with HTML elements in Angular and have references on them you should use `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` decorators. First one is for only one element and second one for more than one.

When using these decorators you should consider `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle method in which you can access references to DOM elements. Under the hood, `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` are using `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`.

Learn and read more about them:

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren